# Как вывести одну строку из символьного массива? (Язык C)

Tags: c, массивы, символы

Увидел лого Onion Omega. Сделал свой логотип три буквы "TIM" и в 6 строк, пытаюсь вывести одну из них и получаю `Ошибка сегментирования (сделан дамп памяти)`.

Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char logo[] = {
        '///////  ///  //        //',
        '/     /  ///  ////    ////',
        '/// ///       // // //  //',
        '  / /    ///  //  //    //',
        '  / /    ///  //        //',
        '  ///    ///  //        //'
    };

    printf(logo[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Как это исправить? Может я делаю что-то не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Массив строк это указатель на указатель строк, или массив указателей строк на стеке.
2. Строки заключаются в 2е кавычки, в одинарные символы.
3. Строки которые не изменяются имеют тип `const char*` не `char*`
4. Массив который не меняется имеет тип `const char* const` (для оптимизации)

```
const char* const logo[] =
{
    "///////  ///  //        //",
    "/     /  ///  ////    ////",
    "/// ///       // // //  //",
    "  / /    ///  //  //    //",
    "  / /    ///  //        //",
    "  ///    ///  //        //"
};

for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(logo) / sizeof(*logo); i++)
{
    printf("%s\n", logo[i]);
}
```

[Test Ideone](https://ideone.com/nnl9a3)

Comment: Вопрос про цикл for: эмм, а зачем делить sizeof(logo) на sizeof(*logo)? Что даёт * в делителе?

Comment: Разделить размер указателя на указатель на размер элемента указателя что бы получить размер массива. Можно использовать `logo[0]`. `*` разыменовывает указатель на указатель извлекая адрес элемента, в данном случае указателя на строку.

Comment: Не переживайте, расчет размеров `sizeof`, производится на этапе компиляции, и в рантайме не сыграет никакой роли.

Comment: Ну...... Вариант https://hastebin.com/abutapagol.cpp весит 8 720 байт, а ваш вариант 8 728 байт. НА 8 БАЙТ БОЛЬШЕ!1!

Comment: Это вы к чему про байты написали?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77411/discussion-between-timoha-timohavich-and-yami).

Comment: Пункт 4 неверен. Ваши `const` - это один и тот же `const`, повторенный два раза. Если вы хотели сделать массив неизменяемым, то `const char *  const logo[]`, а не то, что у вас.

Comment: Если вам так нужен размер поменьше -   попробуйте  `const char * const logo =
    {
        "///////  ///  //        //\n"
        "/     /  ///  ////    ////\n"
        "/// ///       // // //  //\n"
        "  / /    ///  //  //    //\n"
        "  / /    ///  //        //\n"
        "  ///    ///  //        //"
    };

    puts(logo);` :)

Comment: @AnT: точно, перепутал последовательность.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *logo[6] = {
        "///////  ///  //        //",
        "/     /  ///  ////    ////",
        "/// ///       // // //  //",
        "  / /    ///  //  //    //",
        "  / /    ///  //        //",
        "  ///    ///  //        //"
    };

    printf("%s",logo[1]);
    return 0;
}
```